# number of distributions of $m$ balls to $n$ bins

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we have $m$ balls and distribute them into $n$ bins. For $i \in \{0,1,...,m\}$, We let $x_i$ be the number of bins that have $i$ balls in them.

We let $x = (x_i)_{i=0}^m \in \mathbb{N}_{+}^{m+1}$ be the histogram of $x_i$. What is the caridinality of the feasible histogram $x$ (i.e., $x \in \mathbb{N}_{+}^{m+1}$ such that $\sum_{i=0}^m x_i = n$ and $\sum_{i=0}^m i \cdot x_i = m$)?

Any classical results there? Specifically, I'm curious if this number grows polynomially or exponentially fast in $m$ and/or $n$. Thanks so much!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Comment: check out theorem 2 in the link

Comment: @Ben Thanks! I agree Theorem 2 there gives an upper bound, since it calculates the number of feasible $\sum_{i=0}^m x_i = n$. However, this bound can be quite loose here, as it does not use the meaning of $x_i$ at all, i.e., the second equation here.